# Do you "intentionally" boost your bad morale?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Let's say your morale is bad and you want to have a good morale. In this case, could bad morale be something that you want "to boost" or do you just want to fix/improve it?

Comment: Morale is usually described as low or high, not bad or good (it's a positive thing, so _bad morale_ doesn't make sense). Yes, you can boost low morale.

Comment: @KateBunting It's really explanatory. Why don't you write it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Morale* is regarded as a positive thing (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/morale), so it is usually described as *low* or *high,* rather than *bad* or *good*. So, yes, you can *boost, improve* or *raise* your morale.